# Sziklai pair and Darlington pair input impedence

Tags: transistors, bjt, input-impedance

If i remember correctly the input impedence of a BJT is r_pi=Vt/Ibq.
I've read that using those two configurations I get a much higher input impedence. Can someone please tell me why? Maybe some formulas to prove the fact would be appreciated.
Cheers

[image]
[image]

Comment: My  "knee jerk" reaction:) is that you "get a much higher input impedence" since the input base current is beta times smaller than those of a single transistor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply follow the current path. Look at this example:

[image]

Where each transistor has a current gain equal to \$\beta = 99\$

As you can see the input base current is very small due to the BJT's current gain.

And the input signal source see the \$R_E\$ resistor as much large resistor

\$R \approx \beta_1 \times \beta_2 \times R_E \approx 100k\Omega \$

Comment: Shouldn't the collector current of T1 be 13.86 mA?

Comment: @simonov Yes, you are right. I fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer for the Darlington combination (input resistance hie,D):

- hie,D=hie,3 + hfe,3*hie,1 (the input resistance of Q1 appears at the base of Q3 multiplied with the current gain)
- We have hie,1=hfe,1/gm1 with gm1=gm,3*hfe,1 (because Ic1=hfe,1*Ic3).
- From this: **hie,D**=hie,3 + hfe,3/gm,3= **2*hie,3**

Hence, the input resistance of the darlington transistor is twice the input resistance of the first transistor (Q3)

Comment: What do hie and hfe mean?

Comment: OK - I have used the so.called hybrid parameters which describe theBJT as a 4-pole. Physical explanation: hie is the small-signal base-emitter resistance rbe ...and hfe is the small-signal current ratio ic/ib=beta.

Comment: Not sure where the first formula (hie,D=hie,3 + hfe,3*hie,1) comes from...

Comment: Lucky-Luka...the first transistor (QA) has a resistance at its emitter that consists of the B-E path of the second transistor QB - similar to a simple ohmic resistor RE. Hence, we can use the classical feedback formula r1=hie,A + hfe,A*hie,B.

Comment: As you can see, the second term is dominating...and in his example (with numbers) G36 has neglected the first terms. But he has used the same basic feedback formula.

Comment: mmmh... so is his formula right or not? I've read that you wrote it was wrong...

Comment: I have deleted my comment - I have overlooked the 10 ohm resistance in the example. His answer is approximately correct, but he has neglected secondary terms.

Comment: It is easy to see why his result is approximate only: Set RE=0 and the result would be zero, however, this cannot be true because we have still have the resistance of two B-E pathes ...